# Pandas DataFrame correlation on part date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have a Pandas Data Frame that has a DateTime index over a seven-year horizon and price data for 10 different assets.  I want to run the dataframe.corr function to evaluate relationships between the assets, my problem is I want to run the corr function on a specific month.  So in January of all years what is the correlation?

From what I have been reading if I group by the time I could loose the correct progression of time which would make the correlation analysis useless.

How can I group the data frame by month and maintain the sequence of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df['month'] = df.index.month` to extract the month from the DatetimeIndex. Then groupby `month`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = 100
index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='B')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N,3)), index=index)
df['month'] = df.index.month
result = df.groupby('month').corr()
print(result.head(9))
```

yields a DataFrame whose first few rows looks like this:

```
                0         1         2
month                                
1     0  1.000000 -0.000325 -0.208282
      1 -0.000325  1.000000 -0.236316
      2 -0.208282 -0.236316  1.000000
2     0  1.000000  0.056222 -0.010197
      1  0.056222  1.000000 -0.140247
      2 -0.010197 -0.140247  1.000000
3     0  1.000000 -0.064615 -0.111025
      1 -0.064615  1.000000 -0.100798
      2 -0.111025 -0.100798  1.000000
```

This shows the correlations between the columns of the DataFrame.  Notice that
the index is a MultiIndex whose first level is the month and whose second level
refers to one of the two DataFrame columns associated with the correlation.

The `corr` method ignores the index -- it treats the two columns of the DataFrame as arrays.
So there is no problem with the grouped data having gaps in time.

Comment: In addition to my original question can I then filter the corr method by month and column name?  i.e. in month 1 return the correlation data for column 1.

Comment: `result.loc[1,1]` would return the Series of correlations for month 1 and column 1. `result.loc[(1,2),3]` returns the correlation for month 1 between columns 2 and 3.

Comment: See [this section in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for more on slicing DataFrames which have MultiIndexes.

Comment: Exactly what I was after.  Thanks